# Dynamic dependent select box getting null value

Tags: ajax

how to create a dynamic dependent select box which fetches records from database without reload the page using ajax.

here is my code.
ajax-cities.php

```
    <?php


add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
function my_enqueue() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script', plugins_url( '/cities.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery'));
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'ajax_object', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));
}

function my_action() {
$country_id = $_REQUEST['id'];
global $wpdb;
$cities = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM city WHERE country_id='".$country_id."'",13,'gargle'),ARRAY_A);
foreach($cities as $city)
{ ?>
<option value="<?php echo $city["city_id"]; ?>"><?php echo $city["city_name"]; ?></option>
<?php }
die(); 
}

?>
```

page-select-country.php

```
 <?php 
   get_header(); ?>
    <div id="contents">
    <h1>Select Country</h1><br/><br/>
    <form name="form" method="post">
    <label>Country: </label><select name="country" class="country">
    <option>Select Country</option>
    <?php
    global $wpdb;
    $countries = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM country",13,'gargle'),ARRAY_A);
    foreach($countries as $country)
    { ?>           
    <option value="<?php echo $country["country_id"]; ?>"><?php echo $country["country_name"]; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select>
    <label>City: </label><select name="city" class="city">
    <option>Select City</option>
    </select>
    </form>
    </div>
    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

but doesn't shows dependent city name.

Answer (score -1):

add this two hooks at the end of your ajax-cities.php file

```
add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action' );
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action');
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem? Also, please [merge your accounts](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: Work completely.thanx